# Volley , Header Personalizado

Tags: java, android, volley

Actualmente tengo un problema me encuentro con el siguiente código para realizar una llamada POST

```
 public void pendingPaymentsCollections(final Context context, String request, final Response.Listener<GetPendingPaymentsCollections> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    int method = Request.Method.POST;
    String serviceURL = URLLocal;
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, GetPendingPaymentsCollections.class, req, listener, errorListener)
       /* {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("sessionToken", Globals.getSessionToken());
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                return params;
            }
        }*/;
        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown", e);
    }
}
```

Si intento realizar el

```
{
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("sessionToken", Globals.getSessionToken());
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            return params;
        }
    }
```

el servicio me falla , pero no me tira ningun mensaje de error en el LOG , asi comentado el servicio se mapea contra mis clases sin problema y funciona 100% , pero al ponerle el header asi , siempre el servicio se va con el ERROR

Comment: ¿`Globals.getSessionToken()` arroja un valor correcto?

Comment: si el problema venia por otro lado pero tambien tenia ese error que nombres Cedano gracias !

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste entonces?

Comment: @A.Cedano si ya esta resulto gracias Cedano  pero si quieres ayudarme con esta pregunta mia si te agradesco https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131776/paginacion-listview-android-studio?noredirect=1#comment245869_131776