# Paginacion ListView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, paginación

Actualmente tenia un listview donde mostraba

> movimientos

hasta aca todo bien , el problema es que ahora quisiera agregarle paginacion , osea que me muestre 10 y luego con alguna flechita o algo de eso pase a los proximos 10 . ,

Este es mi ListView

Vista :

```
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstbillingnotifications"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/background_dark_grey"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />
```

Modelo :

```
    final ListView lstAuxBilling = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstbillingnotifications);
   AdapterCobroPendiente adapter = new AdapterCobroPendiente(BillingNotifications.this, items);
                        lstAuxBilling.setAdapter(adapter);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        lstAuxBilling.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                                // no se necesita
                            }
                        });
```

Existe alguna forma de trasformar lo que ya tengo para que tenga paginacion o debe presentarse con algun control nuevo , la verdad no tengo en claro esto gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seria algo asi pero con el listview

Comment: Hey Bruno, me parece que no es paginación como la realizada con un ViewPager, te refieres a cargar 10 elementos en el listado y con un indicador cargar los siguientes en el mismo listado?

Comment: Te deje una pequeña imagen que dice que mas de mil palabras

Comment: Creo que haría esto con un [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419)
, mira lo que dice Android: *El widget RecyclerView es una versión **más flexible y avanzada de `ListView`**. Este widget es un contenedor para **mostrar grandes conjuntos de datos que se pueden desplazar de manera muy eficiente** al mantener una cantidad limitada de vistas.* [Te dejo esta respuesta por si te interesa explorar esa posibilidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/116388/29967).+

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Bichare la posibilidad de utilizar un recyclerview

Comment: @Jorgesys re abri mi pregunta aqui ,

Comment: @A.Cedano re abri mi pregunta aqui

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131972/paginacion-en-recyclerview-android-java