# Paginacion en RecyclerView Android Java

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, paginación

Me encuentro con el siguiente RecyclerView

```
         RecyclerView lstMovsWallet = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lstMovsWallet);
         lstMovsWallet.setLayoutManager(new 
         LinearLayoutManager(MovsMobileWallet.this));
         AdapterCobrosPendientesListado adapter = new 
         AdapterCobrosPendientesListado(MovsMobileWallet.this, items);
         lstMovsWallet.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Mi clase de Adapter

```
    public class AdapterCobrosPendientesListado extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCobrosPendientesListado.ViewHolder> {


    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    protected List<MovimientoCuenta> items;

    public AdapterCobrosPendientesListado(Context context, List<MovimientoCuenta> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = data;
    }
    @Override
    public AdapterCobrosPendientesListado.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter_billings_listhistory, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterCobrosPendientesListado.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("###.00");

        String numero =  items.get(position).getNumber();
        String cantidad =  items.get(position).getMonto();
        String fecha =  items.get(position).getFecha();
        String referencia =  items.get(position).getReferencia();
        String debitoCredito = items.get(position).getDebitoCredito();

        holder.number.setText(numero);
        holder.mount.setText(cantidad);
        holder.date.setText(fecha);
        holder.ref.setText(referencia);


        if(debitoCredito.compareTo("DBT")==0){
            holder.title.setText("Pago");
            holder.auxBilling.setImageResource(R.mipmap.signonegativo);
        }
        else {
            holder.title.setText("Cobro");
            holder.auxBilling.setImageResource(R.mipmap.signomas);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


        public TextView number;
        public TextView mount;
        public TextView date;
        public ImageView auxBilling;
        public TextView ref;
        public TextView title ;




        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             number =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberPhoneBilling);
             mount =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtMountBillingNotifications);
             date =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDateBillingNotifications);
             auxBilling = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelBillingNotifications);
             ref =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDateBillingRef);
            title =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.TitleMovs);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //  if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

 /*   // convenience method for getting data at click position
    public String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }*/
}
```

Me gustaría poder agregarle un paginado algo tipo asi  aunque con que sea paginado ya me basta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo la Clase de Movimientos para replicar si alguien necesita

```
> public class MovimientoCuenta {

    private String number;
    private String monto;
    private String moneda;
    private String fecha;
    private String ID;
    private String referencia ;
    private String filtro ;
    private String debitoCredito ;
    private String nombreMov;

    public MovimientoCuenta(String number, String monto, String moneda, String fecha, String ID, String referencia, String filtro, String debitoCredito,String nombreMov) {
        this.number = number;
        this.monto = monto;
        this.moneda = moneda;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.ID = ID ;
        this.filtro =filtro;
        this.referencia=referencia;
        this.debitoCredito =debitoCredito;
        this.nombreMov =nombreMov;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tendrias que hacer, es crear 2 arreglos de tipo `MovimientoCuenta`, uno como ya lo tienes `items` que contendria todos los elementos que necesitas y otro por ejemplo `itemsMostrados` que serian los items que estarias mostrando por pagina.

Aparte, necesitas calcular cuantos items por pagina vas a desplegar, algo por ejemplo asi (de ejemplo asumo que vas a desplegar 10 items por pagina)

```
public int numPaginas(int numItems){
    int numPaginas = numItems/10;
    numItems-=numPaginas*10;
    if(numItems!=0){
        numPaginas++;
    }
    return numPaginas;
}
```

Tambien tendrias que cambiar el valor de items que estas desplegando, en este caso, el tamaño de itemsMostrados

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemsMostrados.size();
}
```

Por ultimo necesitarias una variable que te este indicando en que pagina te encuentras y necesitarias un metodo publico en tu adapter para que cuando en la vista cambies de pagina, actualice los items que estan en `movimientosMostrados`

```
public void setPaginaActual(int paginaActual){
    this.paginaActual = paginaActual;
    itemsMostrados.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i+(paginaActual*10)<items.size()){
            itemsMostrados.add(items.get(i+(paginaActual*10))); 
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

No tengo compilador a la mano pero creo que te puedes dar una buena idea de que tendrias que implementar.